# Finding the Larger Area when the Area Under a Curve is Split

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, definite-integrals

### Finding the Larger Area when the Area Under a Curve is Split

---

Say we have a curve that encloses an area between it and the x-axis. For example, $f(x)=-(x-4)^{2} + 16$.

We then draw in an arbitrary line - $y = 5$ or $y = 3x$ etc. in the example below, we'll add $y = 2x$.

This splits our area into two regions:

[image: Problem]

---

**Question:**

---

> Is there a quick and easy way to find which region is bigger for computing the area of that larger region?

---

My current approach would be as follows for this example:

$\int_0^8 f(x)dx = \frac{256}3$

Solve $f(x) = 2x \implies x = 0$ or $6$

$\int_0^6 f(x)-2x dx = 36$

$\frac{36}{256/3} < 0.5$

$\therefore$ This is the smaller area.

$\therefore$ The area of the larger region created is $\frac{256}3 - 36 = \frac{148}3$ units$^2$.

---

To be clear, this works and is a viable strategy. But when computing by hand and perhaps with more complex functions it becomes a long process. Is there any faster way to determine which area is bigger (not necessarily from "inspection", but just something faster?)

---

**Thanks!**

---

Comment: Here is an idea : You calculate the Area $A$. Then, let's call $g(x)$ the function that separates into regions and call $G(x)$ it's integral. Solve $G(x) = A/2$. if $x$ is not inside, then you have the smaller region.

Comment: I mean if $g(x)$ is not inside of the area bounded by $f$ and $(x,0)$, then you have the smaller region. On the other hand, if it is, then you have the bigger region. I think it's more visual, less computational and easier.

Comment: But i am not sure it works for every curve.

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no quicker or easier way.

In general, even if the line $g(x)$ satisfies $g(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ with $f(x)\geq 0$ you can have some complicated situations with more than 2 pieces if $f$ is a higher degree polynomial function. E.g. $f(x)=-x^4+3x^2+4$ and $g(x)=5$. You have to detect those situations somehow, therefore your solution process needs a minimum complexity.

Comment: Interesting take - though the question focuses on a singular region in a graph (there may be others enclosed, such as by the graphs in polynomials, but only considering one of them, and assuming we know its POIs, is what I was focusing on). Does that change things?

Comment: In my example $f(x)\geq 0$ for $-2\leq x\leq 2$, which defines a single bounded region between the graph of $f$ and the $x$-axis. The POIs of $f$ with $g$ are at the four $x$-coordinares $\frac{1}{2}\left(\pm\sqrt{5}\pm1\right)$. This is computable by moderately difficult biquadratic equations. The example should fit your requirements.